# How do i increase visibility of my work ? Should I ask my skip-level manager directly his criteria for promoting people?

Tags: manager

I am a developer and work for a big firm.
We recently had a change in leadership (manager's manager aka skip)
The new manager is data oriented and I worked on data mining for the past 3 months to get the reports which helped him to prioritize the work for our team. Till last week I was told skip had good visibility and knows how important my work is by my manager.But this week I was told my skip thinks its not good enough for my level let alone consider promotion. I have done couple of other projects which it seems don't have visibility at skip level. How do I ensure I get the rewards I deserve ?

Comment: Voting to close as off topic - "Rather than explaining why your situation is terrible, or why your boss/coworker makes you unhappy, explain what you want to do to make it better"

Answer (score 2):

How important and well performed are not the same.

Yes skip may have been aware of the importance of your work. He got exposure to the specifics of your work and he is not impressed. That is not good news.

Ask your manager what he thinks was lacking in your reports. Work on improving your performance in general.

At this point I don't think you want more visibility with skip.

It is odd that you would be working for skip for 3 months and not received any negative feedback directly. If he feels your work is not up to par and did not share that with you then he does not even consider you an asset worth developing.

Comment: I agree, the visibility is there, but it's negative.

Comment: @Kilisi Do you see any evidence that more visibility is not going to just be more negative.  OP was working directly for the guy and was unaware of poor performance.  Skip has not fired him (yet) - I advise OP to lay low and work on performance.